# Rails 3.2, what's the best way to associate/lookup to a legacy table belonging to another schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

New Rails guy here...

I have a SimpleForm model which belongs to a Parts table belonging to another schema that's not Rails application.

What's the best way to model this association so that my form can do a lookup of the Parts table for part_id and the model can validate the part_id foreign key against the legacy Parts table?

possibilities:
create a database view and activerecord model in rails app?
create a readonly model with query/connection to Parts table?

Please be specific, as I really don't know much within Rails.

I am using Rails with Oracle and Windows, so any solution has to work with these.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using database migration to create a database view and created readonly model for it.
In my SimpleForm, setup belongs_to relationship to the new Parts model and validates_presence_of to enforce the foreign constraint on inserts and edits.
Looks like this is pretty good way to do readonly foreign key reference by granting only "select" permission to legacy table and also setting Rails model to readonly.